# SQLAlchemy @event.listens_for(Class, 'after_insert') for SQL Expression "INSERT INTO table(cols) VALUES (values)"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In my application data will be flowing to postgres database from different system (from hive using scoop). I want to run some code automatically when it is inserted to one of the tables (I created it with sqlaLchemy ORM - I know that after_insert hook doesn't work for sqlAlchemy Core). And for my purpose I can't use postgres trigger.

This is kind of my data model:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, event, DDL

Base = declarative_base()

class MainClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'first_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

@event.listens_for(MainClass, 'after_insert')
def after_insert(Mapper, connection, target):
    connection.execute(DDL(f'''INSERT INTO second_table(name, value) VALUES ('OK!', '{target.name}')'''))


class SecondClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'second_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    value = Column(String, nullable=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
```

What is not working:

```
engine.execute('''INSERT INTO first_table(name) VALUES ('test1')''')
```

What is working (but I can't use such insert in my case):

```
insert = MainClass(name='test2')

with Session(bind=engine) as session:
    session.add(insert)
    session.commit()
```

[Documentations](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html#mapper-events) says:

**method sqlalchemy.orm.MapperEvents.after_insert(mapper, connection, target)**

> Receive an object instance after an INSERT statement is emitted corresponding to that instance.
>
> Example argument forms:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
    @event.listens_for(SomeClass, 'after_insert')
    def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
        "listen for the 'after_insert' event"
```

> This event is used to modify in-Python-only state on the instance after an INSERT occurs, as well as to emit additional SQL statements on the given connection.
>
> The event is often called for a batch of objects of the same class after their INSERT statements have been emitted at once in a previous step. In the extremely rare case that this is not desirable, the mapper() can be configured with batch=False, which will cause batches of instances to be broken up into individual (and more poorly performing) event->persist->event steps.

If this is something that sqlAlchemy ORM events doesn't support. Can you recommend me some workaround?

Comment: You're bypassing the ORM by executing raw SQL, so ORM event listeners won't work.  If you need to execute raw SQL you _might_ be able to do something with [core events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sql-execution-and-connection-events) or add a trigger to the table.

Comment: I was thinking about it but Core Events don't have "before/after insert" listener